# Issue with displaying product image on WooCommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

As WooCommerce doesn't show product images on the order page I created a PHP function to add new columns and to show all the details i need, but i am getting some problems.

When one of the products from old orders is deleted, the order appears with error because that image/product does not exist and give me back critical error.

Can someone give me a possible solution to this case?

I need to tell wordpress "if this image/product doesn't exist or is empty it shows some text"

[image]

```php
// The data of the new custom column in admin order list

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'admin_orders_list_column_content', 1, 2 );
function admin_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ){
    
    global $the_order, $post;
        
    if ('custom_column' === $column) {
       // Start list
        echo '<ul class="orders-list-items-preview">';
        
        // Loop through order items
        foreach($the_order->get_items() as $item) {
          
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $img     = wp_get_attachment_url($product->get_image_id());
            
            if(file_exists($img)){
                $img     = wp_get_attachment_url($product->get_image_id());
            }else{
                echo 'texto2';
            }
   
            $name    = $item->get_name();
            $qty     = $item->get_quantity();
            
            echo "<li>
                <img src=\"$img\" />
                <label>$qty</label> $name
            </li>";
        }
        
        // End list
        echo '</ul>';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_get_attachment_url() will return a string with the attachment URL, otherwise false. So can you add an extra check via an if condition.

Then you get:

```php
function action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {    
    // Compare
    if ( $column == 'custom_column' ) {
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
        
        // Is a WC_Order
        if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
            // Start list
            echo '<ul class="orders-list-items-preview">';
            
            // Loop through order items
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
                // Get product
                $product = $item->get_product();
                
                // Is a WC product
                if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {         
                    // Getters
                    $image_id   = $product->get_image_id();
                    $image      = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id );
                    $name       = $item->get_name();
                    $qty        = $item->get_quantity();
                    
                    // NOT false
                    if ( $image ) {
                        $image_output = '<img src=' . $image . ' width="50" height="50">';
                    } else {
                        $image_output = __( 'Some text', 'woocommerce' );
                    }
                    
                    // Output
                    echo '<li>' . $image_output . '<label>' . $qty . '</label>' . $name . '</li>';
                } else {
                    // Output
                    echo '<li>' . __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) . '</li>';
                }
            }
            
            // End list
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 10, 2 );
```